# Git restore pack index file

Tags: git, restore

I have a git repo with *.pack files - no loose objects.
For some reason ,not related to the question, all *.idx files are lost.
How can I restore them?

thanks

Comment: have you tried `git-repack`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the top of your tree, try running:

```
git index-pack .git/objects/pack/PACK_FILENAME
```

where `PACK_FILENAME` is the name of your pack file.  For instance, a repository I tried this on had the path:

```
.git/objects/pack/pack-7e0af787b3e455fac722264ff05dd0bae7d71625.pack
```

You should do that for each pack file, and you're repository should be in working order again.

Comment: Any idea what causes this?

Comment: @Nepoxx Sadly, no.  It may depend on how things are hosted, or perhaps something on the machine is "cleaning" the files away somehow.  I've personally never seen the problem and have heard very little about it. :-(

Comment: Had to do this a few times.  Thought it wasn't working -- watched the hashes and apparently there were multiple .idx files missing.  `ls -l .git/objects/pack` was helpful to show which .pack files were missing accompanying .idx files.

Answer (score 1):

Note: "`git index-pack --stdin`" needs an access to an existing repository,
but "`git index-pack file.pack`" to generate an `.idx` file that
corresponds to a packfile does not.

That means, from Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) on, you can even restore an `idx` file from outside a Git repo, for testing purpose.

See [commit 29401e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29401e15754518a0e63e00d6cabc5a5f2f9b0973), [commit a3c45d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3c45d126012e01b23edc4923ffddffac61d703b), [commit 7176a31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7176a31444ce5ed683dbd75d2e1e2f89018d0100), [commit de95302](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de95302a4c0c6c733fb734b5a3d3d54dd54ec674) (16 Dec 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff). 
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 49d45de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49d45de1e717df76481feedcdd189b64cea1fabb), 21 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### index-pack: skip collision check when not in repository
>
> You can run "`git index-pack path/to/foo.pack`" outside of a
>   repository to generate an index file, or just to verify the
>   contents.
>   There's no point in doing a collision check, since
>   we obviously do not have any objects to collide with.